# I get an error when starting the Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui, visual-studio-2022

When starting the Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.3, I get the error:

Device error: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\jocaj.android\avd\pixel_5_-*api_31.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5*-_api_31'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=395f2768-4963-41c1-9c2b-ad4931378523'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

I've tried recreating the emulator, reinstalling the android SDK, and it still doesn't start.

Also, I checked the file manager and I see that the file that is mentioned in the error report is not being generated. When I manually add that file, I get this error:

Device error: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=54cff4c8-ea1a-4832-96fb-06842ca3e478'), only 'qemu.' properties are supported

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

Open `Open Panel` on your PC -> `Programs`->`Program and Features`->`Turn Windows feature on and off`

1.disable both `[Hyper-V]` and `[Windows Hypervisor Platform]`.

2.restart PC.

3.enable both `[Hyper-V]` and `[Windows Hypervisor Platform]`.

4.restart PC.